# What is the matter with this equation array?

Tags: equations

This seems to work just fine, but generates all sorts of errors.

```
\[  \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0

\end{array} \right) \times \left( \begin{array}{c}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 & x_9
\end{array} \right) =\left( \begin{array}{c}
3 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}\]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! What kind of errors? Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your second (and third) `\begin{array}` is declared with a single column (`{c}`) but you are using 9 columns (`x_1 & x_2 & `...). You need to either declare more columns, as in the first array, or replace the `&` by ``\\``.

Comment: You cannot have blank lines within an equation.

Comment: Furthermore, mathematically, these matrices can't be multiplied

Answer (score 4):

You should use `\\` in the column vectors to separate entries (`&` separates entries in the same row).

Besides, `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` is out of place.

I suggest to use `pmatrix`, rather than `array`. My personal preference for matrices is `bmatrix`, though.

For unnumbered equations use `equation*`, for numbered ones use `equation`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Unnumbered version:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_6 \\ x_7 \\ x_8 \\ x_9
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\ 5 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Numbered version:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_6 \\ x_7 \\ x_8 \\ x_9
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\ 5 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]